# How to limit nested fields in Tally XML Export Response

Tags: tally

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<VERSION>1</VERSION>
<TALLYREQUEST>Export</TALLYREQUEST>
<TYPE>Collection</TYPE>
<ID>Vouchers</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<DESC>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>CompanyName</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
<SVFROMDATE TYPE="Date">01-01-2023</SVFROMDATE>
<SVTODATE TYPE="Date">01-01-2023</SVTODATE>
</STATICVARIABLES>
<TDL>
<TDLMESSAGE>
<COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No"
ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="Vouchers">
<TYPE> Vouchers : VoucherType</TYPE>
<CHILDOF>$$VchTypeSales</CHILDOF>
<BELONGSTO>Yes</BELONGSTO>
<NATIVEMETHOD>DATE</NATIVEMETHOD>
<NATIVEMETHOD>VOUCHERTYPENAME</NATIVEMETHOD>
<NATIVEMETHOD>ENTEREDBY</NATIVEMETHOD>
<NATIVEMETHOD>PARTYLEDGERNAME</NATIVEMETHOD>
<NATIVEMETHOD>VOUCHERNUMBER</NATIVEMETHOD>
<NATIVEMETHOD>ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST:LEDGERNAME</NATIVEMETHOD>
<NATIVEMETHOD>ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST:INVENTORYALLOCATIONS.LIST:STOCKITEMNAME</NATIVEMETHOD>
</COLLECTION>
</TDLMESSAGE>
</TDL>
</DESC>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

I want to limit the fields in the response against above mentioned XML request, I am successfully able to do it for direct voucher fields but unable to get only "LedgerName" field under the ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST and "StockItemName" field under the INVENTORYALLOCATIONS.LIST.

When I send request to tally with the mentioned body it returns all the fields under ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST as well as INVENTORYALLOCATIONS.LIST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its little complicated,

we need to create a new Report to achieve this.

I tried to restrict child fields but didn't find a way without creating custom report.

I will provide sample custom voucher report. with minimal fields, if you want more fields, you can customize it.

**Input XML**

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
    <VERSION>1</VERSION>
    <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
    <TYPE>DATA</TYPE>
    <ID>TC_VOUCHER</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
    <DESC>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
            <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:xml</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
        </STATICVARIABLES>
        <TDL>
            <TDLMESSAGE>
                <REPORT ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_VOUCHER">
                    <FORM>TC_VOUCHER</FORM>
                </REPORT>
                <FORM ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_VOUCHER">
                    <PART>TC_VOUCHER</PART>
                     <XMLTAG>Voucher.LIST</XMLTAG>
                </FORM>
                <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_BASETALLYOBJECT">
                    <LINE>TC_BASETALLYOBJECT</LINE>
                    <REPEAT>TC_BASETALLYOBJECT:TC_BASETALLYOBJECTCOLLECTION</REPEAT>
                    <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                </PART>
                <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_TALLYOBJECT">
                    <LINE>TC_TALLYOBJECT</LINE>
                    <REPEAT>TC_TALLYOBJECT:TC_TALLYOBJECTCOLLECTION</REPEAT>
                    <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                </PART>
                <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_VOUCHER">
                    <LINE>TC_VOUCHER</LINE>
                    <REPEAT>TC_VOUCHER:TC_VOUCHERCOLLECTION</REPEAT>
                    <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                </PART>
                <PART ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_VOUCHERLEDGER">
                    <LINE>TC_VOUCHERLEDGER</LINE>
                    <REPEAT>TC_VOUCHERLEDGER:ALLLEDGERENTRIES</REPEAT>
                    <SCROLLED>Vertical</SCROLLED>
                </PART>
                <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_BASETALLYOBJECT">
                    <FIELDS>TC_GUID</FIELDS>
                    <XMLTAG>BASETALLYOBJECT</XMLTAG>
                </LINE>
                <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_TALLYOBJECT">
                    <FIELDS>TC_ALTERID,TC_MASTERID</FIELDS>
                    <XMLTAG>TALLYOBJECT</XMLTAG>
                    <USE>TC_BASETALLYOBJECT</USE>
                </LINE>
                <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_VOUCHER">
                    <FIELDS>TC_DATE,TC_VOUCHERTYPE,TC_VOUCHERNUMBER</FIELDS>
                    <XMLTAG>VOUCHER</XMLTAG>
                    <EXPLODE>TC_VOUCHERLEDGER:Yes</EXPLODE>
                    <USE>TC_TALLYOBJECT</USE>
                </LINE>
                <LINE ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_VOUCHERLEDGER">
                    <FIELDS>TC_LEDGERNAME,TC_AMOUNT</FIELDS>
                    <XMLTAG>ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST</XMLTAG>
                </LINE>
                <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_GUID">
                    <SET>$GUID</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>GUID</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_ALTERID">
                    <SET>$AlterId</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>ALTERID</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_MASTERID">
                    <SET>$MasterId</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>MASTERID</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_DATE">
                    <SET>$Date</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>DATE</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_VOUCHERTYPE">
                    <SET>$VOUCHERTYPENAME</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>VOUCHERTYPENAME</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_VOUCHERNUMBER">
                    <SET>$VoucherNumber</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>VOUCHERNUMBER</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_LEDGERNAME">
                    <SET>$LEDGERNAME</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>LEDGERNAME</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                <FIELD ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_AMOUNT">
                    <SET>$AMOUNT</SET>
                    <XMLTAG>AMOUNT</XMLTAG>
                </FIELD>
                <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="NO" ISFIXED="NO" ISINITIALIZE="NO" ISOPTION="NO" ISINTERNAL="NO" NAME="TC_VOUCHERCOLLECTION">
                    <TYPE>VOUCHERS</TYPE>
                    <NATIVEMETHOD>ALTERID</NATIVEMETHOD>
                    <NATIVEMETHOD>ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LEDGERNAME</NATIVEMETHOD>
                </COLLECTION>
            </TDLMESSAGE>
        </TDL>
    </DESC>
</BODY>
```

**OuputXML**

```
<VOUCHER.LIST>
    <VOUCHER>
        <GUID>52889497-5b6b-403d-8f83-224e3c7759b4-00001484</GUID>
        <ALTERID>8816</ALTERID>
        <MASTERID>5252</MASTERID>
        <DATE>1-Apr-23</DATE>
        <VOUCHERTYPENAME>Sales</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
        <VOUCHERNUMBER>1</VOUCHERNUMBER>
        <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
            <LEDGERNAME>ABCD India Pvt Ltd</LEDGERNAME>
            <AMOUNT>35,070.00</AMOUNT>
        </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
        <ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
            <LEDGERNAME>Sales</LEDGERNAME>
            <AMOUNT>35,070.00</AMOUNT>
        </ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
    </VOUCHER>
</VOUCHER.LIST>
```

Note: This XML is generated through [TallyConnector](https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector) and uses object orientation(Voucher Extends BaseTallyObject) which is also supported in TDL
and AutoTDL generation from C# class feature is not released to public.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am new in this area, can you please tell me what is this custom report? and does it make any impact on my tally database or it will only export data out of tally? And is there any documentation (reference) available for tally xml so I could make my own report? Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I already curated the [resources](https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector#other-useful-resources-related-to-tally-integration) for newbies.
For TDL doc [refer this](https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/DeveloperReference/tdlreference/tdl_introduction.htm).
there is no detailed xml docs, but you can [refer this](https://help.tallysolutions.com/article/DeveloperReference/integration-capabilities/case_study_1.htm).

Comment: @AmmarHaider Report is at UI level, it will not effect database, but any query you made through xml will affect tally performance
also don't forget to mark as answer