Fetch all transaction listed in a group voucher
  <HEADER>
    <TALLYREQUEST>Export Data</TALLYREQUEST>
  </HEADER>
  <BODY>
    <EXPORTDATA>
      <REQUESTDESC>
        <REPORTNAME>Voucher Register</REPORTNAME>
        <STATICVARIABLES>
          <SVCURRENTCOMPANY>XXX</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
          <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
        </STATICVARIABLES>
        <FETCHLIST>
          <FETCH>AMOUNT</FETCH>
        </FETCHLIST>
        <FILTERS>
          <FILTER>
            <NAME>LedgerName</NAME>
            <VALUE>2222-158831-2222</VALUE>
          </FILTER>
        </FILTERS>
      </REQUESTDESC>
    </EXPORTDATA>
  </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>

I am trying to fetch the ledger with name "2222-158831-2222" , this ledger has a list of transactions (debit and credit), i would want to fetch the list of these transactions efficiency. If i currently fetch the via the above XML, i get unnecessary data which is take approximately 2 mins for the fetch to complete. If this is not valid way to fetch data tally for my use case, I am also okay to try out other options. Any suggestion is very much appreciated.
The unwanted data that :
 <ALLOWCONSUMPTION>No</ALLOWCONSUMPTION>
      <USEFORINTEREST>No</USEFORINTEREST>
      <USEFORGAINLOSS>No</USEFORGAINLOSS>
      <USEFORGODOWNTRANSFER>No</USEFORGODOWNTRANSFER>
      <USEFORCOMPOUND>No</USEFORCOMPOUND>
      <USEFORSERVICETAX>No</USEFORSERVICETAX>
      <ISREVERSECHARGEAPPLICABLE>No</ISREVERSECHARGEAPPLICABLE>
      <ISSYSTEM>No</ISSYSTEM>
      <ISFETCHEDONLY>No</ISFETCHEDONLY>
      <ISGSTOVERRIDDEN>No</ISGSTOVERRIDDEN>
      <ISCANCELLED>No</ISCANCELLED>
      <ISONHOLD>No</ISONHOLD>
      <ISSUMMARY>No</ISSUMMARY>
      <ISECOMMERCESUPPLY>No</ISECOMMERCESUPPLY>
      <ISBOENOTAPPLICABLE>No</ISBOENOTAPPLICABLE>
      <ISGSTSECSEVENAPPLICABLE>No</ISGSTSECSEVENAPPLICABLE>
      <IGNOREEINVVALIDATION>No</IGNOREEINVVALIDATION>
      <CMPGSTISOTHTERRITORYASSESSEE>No</CMPGSTISOTHTERRITORYASSESSEE>
      <PARTYGSTISOTHTERRITORYASSESSEE>No</PARTYGSTISOTHTERRITORYASSESSEE>
      <IRNJSONEXPORTED>No</IRNJSONEXPORTED>
      <IRNCANCELLED>No</IRNCANCELLED>
      <IGNOREGSTCONFLICTINMIG>No</IGNOREGSTCONFLICTINMIG>
      <ISOPBALTRANSACTION>No</ISOPBALTRANSACTION>
      <IGNOREGSTFORMATVALIDATION>No</IGNOREGSTFORMATVALIDATION>
      <ISELIGIBLEFORITC>Yes</ISELIGIBLEFORITC>
      <UPDATESUMMARYVALUES>No</UPDATESUMMARYVALUES>
      <ISEWAYBILLAPPLICABLE>No</ISEWAYBILLAPPLICABLE>
      <ISDELETEDRETAINED>No</ISDELETEDRETAINED>
      <ISNULL>No</ISNULL>
      <ISEXCISEVOUCHER>No</ISEXCISEVOUCHER>
      <EXCISETAXOVERRIDE>No</EXCISETAXOVERRIDE>
      <USEFORTAXUNITTRANSFER>No</USEFORTAXUNITTRANSFER>
      <ISEXER1NOPOVERWRITE>No</ISEXER1NOPOVERWRITE>
      <ISEXF2NOPOVERWRITE>No</ISEXF2NOPOVERWRITE>
      <ISEXER3NOPOVERWRITE>No</ISEXER3NOPOVERWRITE>
      <IGNOREPOSVALIDATION>No</IGNOREPOSVALIDATION>
      <EXCISEOPENING>No</EXCISEOPENING>
      <USEFORFINALPRODUCTION>No</USEFORFINALPRODUCTION>
      <ISTDSOVERRIDDEN>No</ISTDSOVERRIDDEN>
      <ISTCSOVERRIDDEN>No</ISTCSOVERRIDDEN>
      <ISTDSTCSCASHVCH>No</ISTDSTCSCASHVCH>
      <INCLUDEADVPYMTVCH>No</INCLUDEADVPYMTVCH>
      <ISSUBWORKSCONTRACT>No</ISSUBWORKSCONTRACT>
      <ISVATOVERRIDDEN>No</ISVATOVERRIDDEN>
      <IGNOREORIGVCHDATE>No</IGNOREORIGVCHDATE>
      <ISVATPAIDATCUSTOMS>No</ISVATPAIDATCUSTOMS>
      <ISDECLAREDTOCUSTOMS>No</ISDECLAREDTOCUSTOMS>
      <VATADVANCEPAYMENT>No</VATADVANCEPAYMENT>
      <VATADVPAY>No</VATADVPAY>
      <ISCSTDELCAREDGOODSSALES>No</ISCSTDELCAREDGOODSSALES>
      <ISVATRESTAXINV>No</ISVATRESTAXINV>
      <ISSERVICETAXOVERRIDDEN>No</ISSERVICETAXOVERRIDDEN>
      <ISISDVOUCHER>No</ISISDVOUCHER>
      <ISEXCISEOVERRIDDEN>No</ISEXCISEOVERRIDDEN>
      <ISEXCISESUPPLYVCH>No</ISEXCISESUPPLYVCH>
      <GSTNOTEXPORTED>No</GSTNOTEXPORTED>
      <IGNOREGSTINVALIDATION>No</IGNOREGSTINVALIDATION>
      <ISGSTREFUND>No</ISGSTREFUND>
and much much more.


refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/76840222/13605609

@saivineeth I do understand, that making xml request can hamper tally performance, is there any better way to get data from tally, without the performance hampering ?

if we create custom report that fetch less fields, it will be faster since we are fetching less fields when compared to existing report which fetches more fields

In the steps that you pointed out , for exporting a report. By default tally has a report "Leader Vouchers", when i select this , it will ask me to select a voucher from a list of vouchers. When i select a voucher in the list, the default view is selected , i now change the view to "Bill-wise Details" , I am able to see the entries here. the written xml , when queried (xml) , I get empty response. Please check the below link of details (with screenshot). Hoping for some direction to solve the issue.
XML Written : https://pastebin.com/3muR3p1B

your original question is how to limit fields,
but the xml you used will return all fields, reason for empty response either vouchers are not there for selected ledger and period or name not matching correctly
